# compound interest when interest is a random variable

Tags: probability

Say you are investing, and you on average get $2$% interest per bet, with a standard deviation of $3$%.

How can I get, within a confidence interval, an average amount I will have after 100 bets, if interest compounds?

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe you can take the logarithm of the product, which will turn it into a sum. Then you have a sum of random variables ... Anyway, just a thought.

Comment: I am considering running 10,000 simulations in matlab for 10 year predictions and just taking probabilities. I might be able to work out a confidence interval like that if I just find the expectation of 10,000 simulations. Hoping for a real analytical solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a stochastic differential equation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion.

Say your bet starts at $S_0$, and we model it as $S_t$ over time. Then we can write
$$dS_{t}=\mu S_{t}\,dt+\sigma S_{t}\,dW_{t}$$

where $\mu=.02$, $\sigma=.03$. Here $W$ represents random brownian motion, so $dW$ is simply a draw from the standard normal. So letting each $dt = 1$, your interest rate is $dS_{t}=\mu+\sigma dW_{t}$. The analytic solution to this equation is
$$S_{t}=S_{0}\exp \left(\left(\mu -{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2}}\right)t+\sigma W_{t}\right)$$

The pdf of Brownian Motion $W_t$ is Normal with mean $0$ and variance $t$
$${\displaystyle f_{W_{t}}(x)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi t}}}e^{-x^{2}/(2t)}}$$

We want the pdf of $S_t$, $f_{S_{t}}(x)$. Because $S_{t} = g(W_{t})$ with
$$g(x) = S_{0}\exp \left(\left(\mu -{\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2}}\right)t+\sigma x\right)$$

we can use the change of variable formula
$$f_{S_{t}}(x)=f_{W_{t}}(g^{-1}(x))|\frac{dg^{-1}(x)}{dx}|$$

We have
$$g^{-1}(x) = \frac{\ln{\frac{y}{S_0}}-(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}{\sigma}$$

and 
$$\frac{dg^{-1}(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sigma y}$$

Thus
$$f_{S_{t}}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma y \sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp{\frac{-(\frac{\ln{\frac{y}{S_0}}-(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}{\sigma})^2}{2t}}$$

This is the general solution, plug in your values of $t=100$, $\mu=.02$, and $\sigma=.03$ and you have the pdf for your question!

Funnily enough after all that I'm not sure how to analytically find the mean and standard deviation of $f_{S_{t}}(x)$. But numerically it has mean $\approx 7.244S_0$ and standard deviation $\approx 2.176S_0$.